# Java math operations shorthand?

Tags: java, operators, shorthand

I've been searching but no luck. I want to know if there is a way to perform shorthand operations with the number 1. I know how to do it with addition and subtraction:

```
/*
* Addition: variableName++;
* Addition: variableName +=;
* Subtraction: variableName--;
* Subtraction: variableName -=;
* Multiplication: variableName*=
* Multiplication: variableName**; ?
* Division: variableName /=;
* Division: variableName// ? impossible
* Exponent: variableName ^=;
* Exponent: variableName^^; ?
* Modulo: variableName %=;
* Modulo: variableName%%; ?
*/
```

What about the others? Multiplication, Division, Exponents, Modulo.

Doing division seems almost impossible.

EDIT:
I should have been more specific.
I want to know if there is another version of ++ or - - for the other operators.

Comment: Multiplication : a *= 2 (is similar to a=a*2)
All are like same.

Comment: why not `variableName += 1`, `variableName -= 1`, `variableName *= 1`, `variableName /= 1`, `variable %= 1` ?

Comment: Why would anyone *bother* building a shorthand for in-place multiplication by 1 into the language?

Answer (score 1):

The other mathematical shorthand operators which Java provides are the `+=` (`a = a + number`), `*=`, and so on.

The complete list of operators can be obtained from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
Int a = 5;
a += 1;
a -= 1;
a *= 2;
a /= 2;
```

Are these shorthand enough?

Answer (score 0):

The other operators won't actually change the number.
e.g.
    x = x * 1;
x is unchanged, why would you want a shorthand that doesn't change the value of x?

There are some languages that allow you to make your own shorthand for operators but this requires a bit of research

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no increment or decrement operator like for multiplication and division.Instead we can use them like below

> a *= b (a = a * b)
>
> a /= b (a = a / b) and so on..

also if we want to multiply x by 1 or divide x by 1 then also there will be no effect on the final result..so what's the need